# Running google app sdk dev_appserver.py can't find the local python environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

When I use the dev_appserver.py to run the app.yaml, the code like this:

```
dev_appserver.py --host 0.0.0.0 --enable_host_checking false app.yaml
```

but it has the import error:

```
No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

But I had installed it in my python environment. When I open python and import it in the same file ,it can work:

```
root@localhost:/home/ftp/global_change/site-py# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import googleapiclient.discovery
>>>
```

So why my dev_appserver.py can't import those modules that I have installed in python2.7.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had solved this problem. The dev_appserver.py built a virtual environment when ran it. So it had this error.

Comment: Hi zi yang, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: The google SDK would create a virtual environment for its own project, this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27 helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[@ziyang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10638513/zi-yang) solved his own question. Apparently the `dev_appserver.py` built a virtual environment when ran it, which had the error described in the quesiton.

[@ziyang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10638513/zi-yang) managed to solve it by following the GCP documentation about [using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)